# Pimcore How to display custom error message in error message box

Tags: message, pimcore

Hi i am working on pimcore cms.

I am calling custom API while saving objects and it has some custom error message.

Right now pimcore showing

> "Object Could not saved".

**How to display custom message instead of this default message in error box ?**

My API returns error message whenever error occurs but I am stuck on how to pass it with pimcore Error message.

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you are using Pimcore events to do what you are trying to achieve. To display custom message, you just need to throw ValidationException like this:

```
throw new \Pimcore\Model\Element\ValidationException("This is your custom error message", 1234);
```

This is also described in the section `Example of custom error handling using the Event API` of the documentation here:

https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Extending_Pimcore/Event_API_and_Event_Manager.html

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but it is very important to also know, that you need to set your local environment as `PROD` for this to actually work!

Otherwise only a generic error message will be shown: `Saving failed!`

So, in .env file set:

```
# ENVIRONMENT (dev|test|stage|prod)
APP_ENV=prod
PIMCORE_ENVIRONMENT=prod
```

Due to probably a Pimcore bug, in case you are working on a DEV env (which of course we do locally) the response from back-end will be polluted with the Symfony exception layout and information. Thus the generated JSON response will be invalid and the front-end will show the generic response: 'Saving failed!'

So, in order to test that your code is working (e.g.: your custom listener is throwing an exception with a custom error message), you need to set temporarily your local env to PROD, test your error message and then revert to DEV env. When deployed to PROD it should work fine.

Comment: Tested on Pimcore 10 -- \Pimcore\Model\Element\ValidationException works fine even in DEV environment